# Help in reading Set Notation

Tags: optimization, notation

I am reading the paper on optimization and the following is the notation:
[image]
I am trying to understand how to read it because there is equality and inquality in the same equation. I know the norm term but i dont understnd what this equation as a whole is read as.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but we read the equation as: a set $B_{r_j}(\mathbf{x}_j)$ is defined as a set which consists of $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathcal{X}$ which satisfies $\|\mathbf{x}_j-\mathbf{x}\|\le r_j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an equation or an inequation: that is just the [set-bulder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). Specifically, the line reads:

> $B_{r_j}(x_j)$ is the set of all the elements $x$ of the set $\mathcal X$ which satisfy $\lVert x-x_j\rVert\le r_j$.

In oter words: $B_{r_j}(x_j)$ is the set of the elements of $\mathcal X$ which are in closed ball with center $x_j$ and radius $r_j$ with respect to the norm $\lVert \bullet\rVert$.

Answer (score 3):

I would read this as "The set $B_{r_j}(x_j)$ is equal to the set of all $x$ in the set $\chi$ such that $|| x_j - x|| \leq r_j$."